# Change Base Shapekey without changing the other shapekeys

Tags: shape-keys

I started adding shapekeys and then noticed I want to edit my basemesh. Unfortunately the changes in the base shapekey affect the other shapekeys. Is it possible to change the base shapekey and not have it affect the other shape keys?

Comment: Have you tried using hooks instead?  In Edit mode, select the vertice(s) concerned, press CTL-H and select "Hook to New Object".  An empty will appear at the vertice which is in effect an object and can be keyframed.  Changes made later won't (or shouldn't) affect it's other keyframes.  The drawback is that you have to make another central empty and parent the model to that if you're to move the model about.  Also parent the hook to this empty.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
Two objects with the same vertices will be required. So make a copy before you change basis of one of the object.

- Make modification to the basis.
- Create a new shape key on the object with modified basis.
- Select the newly created shape key for the object with modified basis.
- Select the shape key you want to keep the old position from the object with original basis.
- Object Mode: select object (original basis) then shift select object( modified basis)
- On the shape key drop down menu select "Join as shapes"
- A new shape key will be created with the old position.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the basis then it will change all the following shapekeys but to change the other ones without it editing the basis you have to so it in edit mode

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTY7xTWB6-o

He shows how to update your current shapekeys, including your basis

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the best way to do it, but what I did was:

1. Make a new intermediate parent shapekey off the basis blendshape, parented to itself
2. Parented all of my existing shapekeys to this intermediate parent
3. Modified my basis blendshape accordingly (in this case, doing "blend from shape" from the blendshape I wanted to swap to the basis shape)
4. Parented the intermediate back to basis

This seems to have worked correctly, and allowed me to preserve the original blendshape as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out... Before making changes to the Basis, change the "Relative To" option to the shape key itself. Then select the icon to edit and tab into edit mode modify the Basis, tab back out of edit mode, then change back the "Relative to" on the shape key back to Basis. I am using Blender 3.3.0